# Using Cassandra Secondary Index with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

Cassandra 1.1 documentation says that now it is possible to use secondary indexes to get a slice of rows for Hadoop processing. Does this mean that now it is possible to achieve this while using RandomPartitioner unlike earlier version where usage of OrderedPartitioner was required for this? However going through ColumnFamilyInputformat code I still see an assertion where it enforces that OrderedPartitioner need to be in place for this to happen. Any ideas on this?